# I have a problem with Python in writing a function of a square

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def Quadrato():
    primariga = print("+", " - "*4, "+", " - "*4, "+")
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    primariga = print("+", " - "*4, "+", " - "*4, "+")
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    primariga = print("+", " - "*4, "+", " - "*4, "+")


Quadrato()

# UNA MANIERA SINTATTICAMENTE PIù ORDINATA SI HA QUANDO:
def quattrovolte(f):
    f()
    f()
    f()
    f()


def Quadrato_1():
    primariga = print("+", " - "*4, "+", " - "*4, "+")
    secondariga = print("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|")
    print(primariga)
    quattrovolte(secondariga)
    print(primariga)
    quattrovolte(secondariga)
    print(primariga)

Quadrato_1()
```

What I'm trying to do, is trying to Draw the square in the first function in a better and simpler way.Instead, I get an error that says: "NoneType" object is not callable. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What do you think the return type of `print` is?

Comment: you’re trying to print a print statement, that seems wrong

Comment: Where did you define the function `f()`? I don't see you defining that. Thats why, when you are calling `quattrovolte(secondariga)` its not getting the function name.

Comment: @shariful: `f()` is the name of `secondariga` in function `quattrovolte`; it's passed as an argument

Comment: You cannot pass a value and call it as a function.

Comment: @shariful you can pass functions as arguments, just not like OP is trying to do

Comment: @shariful sure you can. Python functions are just objects, like any other object, and can be passed and returned from a function. That is, functions are first-class objects in Python. Indeed, *everything* is an object in Python, including, for example, classes.

Comment: You are right. @UnholySheep I kind of expressed it loosely in the context of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a `print` statement to a `print` statement. However, `print` only returns `None` (in addition to printing something on the screen).

A way to  get around this problem is to define `primariga` and `secondariga` as strings:

```
def Quadrato_1():
    primariga = "+" + " - "*4 + "+" + " - "*4 + "+"
    secondariga = "|" + " "*12 + "|" + " "*12 + "|"
    print(primariga)
    for i in range(4):
        print(secondariga)
    print(primariga)
    for i in range(4):
        print(secondariga)
    print(primariga)

Quadrato_1()
```

returning this:

```
+ -  -  -  - + -  -  -  - +
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
+ -  -  -  - + -  -  -  - +
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
|            |            |
+ -  -  -  - + -  -  -  - +
```

I also added two `for` loops as a nicer way to repeat `secondariga` four times.

Comment: @Norman Facco. If his answer is ok for you, you can click on the check button, it gives reputation points and some privilege for the user.

Comment: Nitpick: In Python 3 `print` is a function, not a statment

Answer (score 0):

In this, you're trying to define a variable with a `print()` function. `print()` does not return anything when it runs, so setting a variable to it will result in it being a pointer to nothing, as no object was ever created.

Here's what you should do:

```
def square():
    #setting these to a tuple and not a function.
    p = ("+", " - "*4, "+", " - "*4, "+") 
    q = ("|", " "*12, "|", " "*12, "|" )
    order = (p,q,q,q,q,p,q,q,q,q,p)
    for i in order:
        print('',join(i))

square() #if all goes well, this will print a square into the terminal. ::))
```